# Bootstrapping only selected post-hoc contrasts for multiple regression

Tags: r, multiple-regression, confidence-interval, bootstrap

Is is statistically correct to claim that I proved (with p-value < 0.05) that "mean of versicolor group > mean of setosa group" if all I did was to bootstrap a 95% confidence interval for "setosa - versicolor" contrast like in this code?

```
require(tidyverse)
require(car)
require(emmeans)

m <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, data=iris)
m.boot <- Boot(m, function(.) {
  t <- summary(emmeans(., pairwise ~ Species))$contrasts
  setNames(t$estimate, t$contrast)[1]
})
confint(m.boot)
## Bootstrap quantiles, type =  bca 
##
##                        2.5 %     97.5 %
## setosa - versicolor -1.104946 -0.7687479
```

If "Yes", what would be the proper reference to support such analysis?

I suspect there must be a catch here. I mean, why would anyone bother to develop packages like "ARTool" if a simple bootstrap will do... If so, can you suggest an alternative way? Preferably, unlike ARTool, one allowing to fit arbitrary linear models and visualize confounder-controlled group means on the original scale (not transformed to ranks).

In reality we need to analyze several contrasts in our (not quite balanced and normally distributed) observational experiment, designed as 3-way ANCOVA with a confounding variable.

Comment: Is it possible to pare down this post into a single, focused question with a minimally reproducible example? I am having a hard time understanding what you're really asking.

Comment: to AdamO: Please tell me which parts are not reproducible, I will be happy to clarify. I thought linear model with 2 factors is "minimal" to fully illustrate my questions: regression is complicated enough, so that post-hoc analysis is "a must" to interpret it. My (oversimplified) main question: Is it correct to "directly bootstrap" just a single contrast (say "A,X - B,X") to get 95% CI and p-value for it?

Comment: *minimally* reproducible means that the fewest lines of code necessary to convey the problem are presented. Perhaps you can focus on another example with a single contrast.

Comment: Regarding “forcing emmeans...,” you might consider using `emmeans::contrast` with a specified list of contrast coefficients, and/or a `by` variable. It’s all right there in the documentation.

Comment: to rvl: Thank you, of course I RTFM about "list of contrast coefficients". I could unite the coefficient lists from "pairwise ~ abc|xy" and "pairwise ~ xy|abc". But do you agree that this is an extremely inconvenient way of specifying "custom" sets of contrasts as compared to using human readable formula?

Comment: to AdamO: I will really appreciate your help to simplify the code. About bootStatistics: (1) without "capture.output(...)" wrapper we will drown in emmeans' warnings; (2) the "list of coefficients" alternative to contrast selection is even more cumbersome. About mySummary: the "tryCatch(...)" wrapper is a quick fix to boot.ci() inconsistent behavior. Just use the commented "return" in bootStatistics and watch standard summary() and confint() crash! I wish there will be an easy standard way to compute both 95% CI and p-value for bootstrap dataset, handling variable names correctly.

Comment: @danil I guess inconvenience is in the eyes of the beholder. However, I would suggest doing the EMMs and contrasts separately, and use something more like `emm <- emmeans(m, ~ abc*xy)` and then `pairs(emm, by = "xy") + pairs(emm, by = "abc")` which does the two sets of pairwise comparisons and then combines them into one object.

Comment: By the way, `coef(contrast(...))` may be used to extract the contrast coefficients that were used.

Comment: I edited to simplify (perhaps oversimplify) my question. @rvl Thank you! This pairs() + pairs() trick will make my life simpler (and my r code cleaner).